# MS Dynamics CRM data connection in Excel 2016 failed

Tags: excel, connection, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am getting error establishing a data connection in excel to import MS Dynamics report. Here what I have followed so far:

1. Went to Data tab >> New Query >> From Online services >> From Dynamics CRM online.
2. A pop up comes up saying Enter URL. Refer to Image below>

I put the URL I got from developer resource in MS CRM that exactly looks like this format

[image]

3. This is the url I am using (cannot reveal org name)-

   > https://**orgname**.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
4. When I click next, I get this error -

   > OData: The given URL neither points to an OData service or a feed: 'https://**orgname**.api.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc'.

Why I am getting this error and what is the possible resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `OrganizationData.svc`.

The URL will look like: `https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/`

Note the trailing slash `/` at the end of URL.

[Refer this](http://survivingcrm.com/2013/12/connecting-crm-online-odata-feed-excel-2013-power-query/)

> Settings – Customizations – Developer Resources menu

[image]

Comment: thanks for your response. but I am still getting error. Error says invalid endpoint url. Not sure why i am getting this.

Comment: @praveenbehera did you grab the URL from Settings – Customizations – Developer Resources menu ?

Comment: Yes @Arun, the one under Organization Data Sevice, but no luck!

Comment: @praveenbehera Are you able to browse that URL in browser? Try adding AccountSet at the end & try in excel.

Comment: Hi @Arun, thank for the reply, not sure what will appear when run the url on browser- i see 1 message - You have created a service.

To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax: and some set of Csharp and vb code.

Comment: Also, I don't see CSDL in my dynamics org, i see only WSDL which you have highlighted.

Comment: Can you update the question with crm version, screenshot of both comments.. (I want to see the URL, don't forget to mask the org name)